# Responsive menu design on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am looking to make a Responsive menu which will have a Menu button for small screen and on click menu show slide down and menu button will change to `X`

Something like as show in image below
[image]

I am trying to do same but got on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbaXEq

Not sure how to change Menu Button in to X and back to normal on toggle. Button is not also aligned with logo.

Any help or pointer to make it look professional.

UPDATE:

I have done made it so far http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVbGbR?editors=110

Comment: couldn't you use any external CSS like bootstrap?

Comment: try [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: add floating to logo

Comment: I made it so far looking http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVbGbR?editors=110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGwegr

Just use css to transform your button to `X` and back:

```
.menu-btn-w {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}

/* these styles are used for the mb lines, when your button has the class transform-mb*/
.menu-btn-w.transform-mb .mb-1 {
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-btn-w.transform-mb .mb-2 {
   display: none; /* hide the second line with css */
}
.menu-btn-w.transform-mb .mb-3 {
   margin-top: -10px;  /* pull the third line up to make a correct X */
   -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

now toggle this class `transform-mb` on click:

```
$('.menu-btn-w').click(
    function() {
      $('.mobile-menu-w').toggle();
      $(this).toggleClass("transform-mb");
    }
);
```

Comment: Thaank you so much, i will try to work on other half.

Comment: Just one question, why is menu button not aligned to logo, I want it to be aligned right of the page and aligned as show in image

Comment: Make the logo `float: left`, shown in the updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGwegr (a div makes on default a break)

Comment: I fixed issue they where  due to floating , just need to fix menu position on click http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVbGbR?editors=110